# What to do with pending transactions even after too many reattachments?

Tags: transaction, wallet, reattach, private-key

If any transaction is pending for hours/days even after reattaching and promoting it (*while connected with updated node and keep changing them for reattaching again*), shall I resend it to receiver's different address?

Both of the pending transactions will try to spend from the same address of my wallet. And that will reveal 50% of the private key while they are in pending state. Right?

what should I do in this case? Keep reattaching or send again to a new address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep promoting the pending transaction. You should also select a properly sync fullnode. (see http://iota.dance/nodes/).

As you mention yourself, sending to a different address is a double spend, it will reveal another portion of your key... and there is absolutely no guarantee that this new transaction will confirm faster.

Comment: Agreed. I am using  http://iota.dance/nodes/ to fetch latest node info. But it means multiple _parallel_ transactions can't be made using wallet or client as user can't choose address to spend from and it will choose same address (starting from first index)

Comment: Indeed, you can't safely have multiple pending transactions with the current wallet. But remember that iota is targeting machine-2-machine transactions where one machine can have a smart implementation of it's addresses pool (requirements depending on the service implemented by the machine)

Comment: True. Excited to see update on address pooling :)